# Does sequential work on CC.Net 1.6?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Im on CC.Net 1.6, where `<sequential>` is supposed to work.

When I try to run it with something like the sample shown below, I get ERROR level exceptions saying "Unused node detected" on the sequential node.

What am I missing?

Mark

```
<sequential>
   <tasks>

   <powershell>yada...</powershell>       

   <buildpublisher>yada...</buildpublisher>

   <ftp>yada...</ftp>        

    </tasks>        
</sequential>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have put the sequential node in the right place, i.e. inside another tasks node where it belongs? I tried constructing the project configuration below and it passed validation without errors.

```
<project>
    <name>Test project</name>
    <tasks>
        <sequential>
            <tasks>
                <powershell>
                    <script>script.ps1</script>
                </powershell>
                <buildpublisher />
                <ftp>
                    <ftpFolderName>upload</ftpFolderName>
                    <localFolderName>test</localFolderName>
                    <userName>user</userName>
                    <password>pwd</password>
                    <serverName>ftp.server.com</serverName>
                </ftp>
            </tasks>
        </sequential>
    </tasks>
</project>
```

It's also not clear from your post why exactly you need the sequential task. The task in CC.Net are executed sequentially by default so you would only need to use it inside a parallel task to specify a block of tasks to be executed sequentially:

```
<project>
    <name>Test project</name>
    <tasks>
        <parallel>
            <tasks>
                <sequential>
                    <tasks>
                        <!-- other tasks here -->
                    </tasks>
                </sequential>
                <sequential>
                    <tasks>
                        <!-- other tasks here -->
                    </tasks>
                </sequential>
            </tasks>
        </parallel>
    </tasks>
</project>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Damir - Thank you:)  It wasnt clear from the documentation if the tasks were truly sequential or not. Ive stumbled across conflicting info on that was just being extra careful. That aside, you've nailed the problem - I didnt have a '<tasks>' node as a parent to '<sequential>'.

Comment: sequential task is also used for the "continueOnFailure" flag, by default any failure will stop the build. By setting continueOnFailure=true, all tasks are run independently from failing tasks, this is often used for running multiple test fixtures, were you may want to get all the test results.